# bringing local storage page to page not working

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a select element that changes the theme of my website. In it, I use local storage to change the theme on every page, even though the changer is just on the home page. It sets the local storage key, but I can't get it to pull up on the other pages. It works on the home page, though. My code to retrieve the local storage is

```
function setTheme() {
theme = window.localStorage.getItem('theme');
document.getElementById('themepicker').setAttribute('href', theme);
document.getElementById(theme).setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
}
```

The code that changes it is

```
        function changeTheme(theme) {
        sltr = document.getElementById('themepicker');
        theme = theme + '.css';
        sltr.setAttribute('href', theme);
        window.localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);
    }
```

The function is run when the page is loaded.

Comment: where are you running `window.localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);`?

Comment: The Homepage of the site

Comment: can you either post the full code for both set and load, or make an online demo?

Comment: I just updated it

Comment: is it possible your homepage has a different domain name than your other site pages?  even if it's something simple like one uses a `www.` and the others don't?

Comment: No, unless using github pages counts

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are only resetting `theme` to `theme` instead change the theme to the new theme and `theme` was never defined or set to the new `theme`.

Comment: Could you explain that again. I don't get it when there are 6 themes in one sentence